# How to get a list of checked item from Check List VB. Net Winform

Tags: vb.net

After several hours of trying, I was able to get a Check List binded to SQL source. However, now I would like to retrieve all of the items in the check list that are checked. I tried the above code but it does not work

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To checkList_Facility.Items.Count - 1
        If (checkList_Facility.GetItemChecked(i)) = True Then
            MsgBox(checkList_Facility.Items(i))
        End If
    Next
```

Binding Code:

```
            Dim queryString As String = "SELECT Facility FROM Database.dbo.Facility"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim var As New DataTable
        Dim source As New BindingSource
        source.DataSource = dataReader
        CheckList_Facility.DataSource = source
        CheckList_Facility.ValueMember = "Facility"
        connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`CheckedItems` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx) instead?

EDIT:

```
dim itemChecked as Object
For Each itemChecked In checkList_Facility.CheckedItems
   MsgBox(itemChecked.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: Hello Shakalpesh for your answer. I tried but it returns "System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal"

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to bind the data to the checkedlistbox?

Comment: @user2103670: Were you able to fix it? If yes, please paste it the code in the comments below.

Comment: I am working on it. I updated the question with the binding code. It does show all facility in the list

Answer (score 1):

[CheckedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx) seems to be a good option. Here is how it works. For simplicity, suppose your underlying business object (DataSource) is a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
With dict
  .Add("1", "One")
  .Add("2", "Two")
  .Add("3", "Three")
End With
```

And you have the following binding:

```
With CheckedListBox1
  .DataSource = dict.ToList
  .ValueMember = "Key"
  .DisplayMember = "Value"
End With
```

It seems that Microsoft do not want us to use this approach, probably due to compatibility issues. You know this because `.DataSource` and other members are hidden in intellisense. However, for simple setup such as the above, it works, just don't rely on intellisense in typing these members.

Now let's say you have a button with the following code in it:

```
Dim v = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
```

In this case `v` is a collection of underlying business objects, for the above it will be collection of `KeyValuePair(Of String, String)`.

In your case your business object is of type `DataRecordInternal`, so you have to expect this type to be returned and account for it in code. Note that it may not have a *good* behavior of `ToString()`, so this will not work as you expect it:

```
MsgBox(checkList_Facility.Items(i))
```

I believe you are looking to do some processing instead, messaging a user about every checked item is not very useful. So instead you may want to have a different code, such as:

```
Dim record As DataRecordInternal = checkList_Facility.Items(i)
'do some processing on record variable
```

Comment: Oh, I do not intend to message it to the user. However, in order to see the result, I often use msg to display for testing purpose.  I intended to write some queries with options from user, the problem is my company is does not even has a good IT and we often change stuff around - I have to choose data binding instead of making a fix choices.  I am business person but I have to do some coding to help my work faster.

Comment: @user2103670: according to your comment from another answer, chances are you need a namespace prefix: `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal`

Comment: I tested but I could not use "Dim record As DataRecordInternal = CheckedList_Facility.Items(i)" because it said System.Common.DataRecordInternal is not accessible in this context because it is "FRIEND"

Comment: I tried to have "Imports System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal" but it says something about "FRIEND"

Comment: @user2103670: Looks like we could use more information about your problem. Please post another question and include as much info as possible in it.